# How can I stop the game from pausing when the window doesn't have focus?

Tags: pokemon-uranium

The game pauses everytime I click out of the game to do something else, which is really annoying.

Is there any configuration I can change in order for the game to continue running after it has lost focus?

Comment: (assuming this feature doesn't exist) you should try to contact the devs here: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeLLH3QD1ybtdEolUYEmgCNouYP9-JQxmqaTvmkj8mIPWCieg/viewform?c=0&w=1 (I found the link from here: http://pokemon-uranium.tumblr.com/faq)

Comment: You can write a macro that forces a specific window to regain focus when lost, but that would only fix your problem if the game naturally unpauses itself when back in focus.  Furthermore, it will potentially screw up whatever your are doing in the background (e.g. try dragging and dropping a file in some windows explorer or equivalent program etc).

Answer (score 7):

Pokemon Uranium is made in RPG Maker XP. When tabbed out, all scripts stop running, but all audio continues playing. This can be seen documented in [this](http://forums.rpgmakerweb.com/index.php?/topic/46286-rmxp-bgm-bgs-me-play-when-tabbed-out-of-project/) forum post. There is no way to fix this, as it is an engine limitation. This limitation was removed in RPG Maker VX, but Pokemon Uranium runs in XP, and it seems this limitation is unlikely to ever be removed.

[Further Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemonzetaomicron/comments/1vxgl1/is_it_possible_to_make_it_so_that_the_game_doesnt/)

Comment: The OP is asking for a way to stop the pausing.  That post just details a bug where the sound doesn't pause when the game pauses via loss of focus.

Comment: @camelCase _but the sounds in a project will keep running when a game is running but is tabbed out of, unlike scripts and other events_

This isn't a bug (Well, it might be, but it's beside the point). It describes how RPG maker XP works. When the window isn't the active window, audio keeps playing, but the scripts stop running, therefore the game stops, but the audio continues. This is a limitation of the engine, and answers the OP's question.

Comment: Its a bug, because it affects audio clips.  I remember some games going out of sync when you lost focus when 2 "actors" were talking.  Sure, background music continuing to play could be seen as intentional, but like I say, it definitely affected audio clips too.

Comment: Regardless, it answers OP's question. Further sources have been added in case any doubt was held.